# OOP public variable problem

Tags: php, oop

Can someone please help for some reason i can echo and set the file and department variables in my export function but when i try to call them in exportdata they are null.

```
Class customersController Extends baseController {
    public $file;
    public $department;


    public function export() {
        $this->registry->template->title = 'Ainsworthstudio - Export Customer Info';

        $this->registry->model->createModel('db', 'db');
        $this->registry->model->createModel('customers', 'customers');
        $this->registry->model->getModel('db')->addConnection("localhost", "sdgsdg", "sdg0", "sdg");
        $data = $this->registry->model->getModel('customers')->getDepartments();

        while(list($k, $v)=each($data))
            $$k = $v;

        $this->registry->template->departments = $data;
        $this->registry->template->show('customers_export');
    }

    public function exportcheck() {
        if(!empty($_POST['filename'])) {
            $this->file =  $_POST['filename'];
            $this->department =  $_POST['depart'];

            echo "<div class='error_message'>Exported Successfully</div>";

            echo $this->file;
            echo $this->department;
            echo 'success';
        } else {
            echo "<div class='error_message'>Wrong Username or Password</div>";
            exit();
        }
    }

    public function exportdata() {
        return $this->file;
        return $this->department;

        echo $this->department;
    }
}
```

Comment: It'd be awfully nice if you could indent your code and remove unnecessary code, so people willing to help you could read it more easily. Secondly, are you ever setting anything on these properties?

Comment: Yes, clear code and show how you are use it. PS. Its a CI framework, am I right?

Comment: Sorry its a framework i'm building i still have to simplify a lot of things into functions i just wanted to get everything working

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
public function exportdata() {
    return $this->file;
    return $this->department;

    echo $this->department;
}
```

You're returning the value of `$this->file` not echoing.

If you try `echo $myCustomersController->exportdata()` you'll see it echo the value of `$this->file`

If you want to `echo` the values remove the `return`s

```
public function exportdata() {
    echo $this->file;
    echo $this->department;
}
```

Comment: yep.  appears everything is assigned as desired, the echo just never runs!

Comment: i tried it with echo and nothing happens. I'm using an MVC so every function on their is a different page does that make it not work>

Comment: @Josh, yes it would. Essentially, the code for `exportcheck()` is not being called when you're view the page corresponding to `exportdata()` and hence the `$this->file` and `$this->department` values are not set. What you need to do is take the code from `exportcheck()` that sets the `$this->file` and `$this->department` values and separate it out into a function that you can call from both `exportcheck()` and `exportdata()`.

Comment: im using ajax the actual form post is calling exportcheck which if success goes to exportdata

Comment: So when the user clicks submit, you're posting to exportcheck the if successful the browser redirects to exportdata? If so, rather then setting department and file to $this, set them to the session or a cookie. That way you can persist them between requests